Pinescript block of code executes more than once despite the flag
Can someone tell me, why does this code execute more than once?
var testalert = true
if testalert and timenow > 1724003180000
    strategy.order("TestLong", strategy.long, limit=61000,  qty=0.5, comment="ENTER-LONG_BINANCE-FUTURES_BTCUSDT_Ondrejs-Bot_30M_472398966e86382d84031451")
    label.new(x=bar_index, y = open, text=str.tostring(timenow), color=color.red, style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.white, size=size.large)
    testalert := false

For the record, I am setting this in the strategy settings:
calc_on_every_tick=true

But that still doesn't explain it, does it?

try varip testalert = true

var will still allow intra-bar updates. You need varip.

varip (var intrabar persist) is the keyword used for the assignment
and one-time initialization of a variable or a field of a user-defined
type. It’s similar to the var keyword, but variables and fields
declared with varip retain their values between executions of the
script on the same bar.

Run below test code on seconds timeframe and you should see the behavior of var vs varip in the data window.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var flag1 = false
varip flag2 = false

var float close1 = na
varip float close2 = na

if (barstate.isnew)
    flag1 := false
    flag2 := false
else
    if (not flag1)
        close1 := close
        flag1 := true
    
    if (not flag2)
        close2 := close
        flag2 := true

plotchar(flag1, "flag1", "", color=color.green)
plotchar(flag2, "flag2", "", color=color.red)
plotchar(close1, "close1", "", color=color.green)
plotchar(close2, "close2", "", color=color.red)


amazing, thank you so much
